# Deplane! Deplane! (Or: RGBRGBRGB => RRRGGGBBB?)

Tags: code-challenge, array

Imagine bytes in memory for an RGB image--R and G and B represented by bytes in sequence.  If an image is NxM then the memory layout will be M repetitions for vertical scanlines of 3*N bytes in sequence for the horizontal pixels.  (As one might expect.)

A mandate has come down from on high that you need to be able to isolate contiguous color planes.  You might be asked for the R, G, or B plane.  When you give back the plane it must be the N*M bytes in sequence for that color.

Yet there is a twist: You cannot use additional memory proportional to the size of the image.  Thus you must shuffle the bytes somewhere inside of the existing RGB data to provide the contiguous plane for the requested color.  *And* you must be able to recover the original image when processing of that color plane is finished.

The image size is actually not relevant to the problem as it operates on the buffer as a whole.  Input is bytes *(expressed as hexadecimal ASCII)* followed by which plane to extract:

```
00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEE
G
```

Output is the extracted color plane, then the original input *(also in hexadecimal ASCII):

```
114477AADD
00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEE
```

Where you shuffle the memory is up to you.  But you must actually shuffle the data to produce contiguous bytes *(requiring the client to use an iterator is cheating)*.  And you must be able to reverse the operation to restore the original information.

Lowest big-O implementation wins.  Between two implementations with equal big-O performance... winner decided by code golf rules.

Comment: Surely the `G` channel of the sample input is `0235689BCE`? And does the restriction on additional memory also apply to the print operation, or is that allowed to copy?

Comment: @petertaylor how do you figure G as not being the second byte and every third byte after?  Regarding restrictions just imagine a buffer of a million by a million image... Your print cannot depend on allocations scaling with the image size.

Comment: Is input in raw bytes, or in the [base-16](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-8) encoding shown in the examples? (I think that's also @PeterTaylor's question.)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, hex strings.  Clarified.

Comment: If they are hex strings, why not simply convert them to raw bytes, and then you'll have a lot of freed memory to do whatever you wish...

Answer (score 3):

## C

only shuffle, not print

lenght in bytes, not pixels

plane: 0,1,2 for R,G,B

not checked!

```
void deplane(unsigned char *data, int length, int plane) {
    unsigned char *t = data;
    unsigned char *s = data + plane;
    unsigned char p;
    while (s < data + length) {
        p = *s; *s = *t; *t = p;
        t++; s += 3;
    }
    // now plane start at data
    while (t > data) {
        s -= 3; t--;
        p = *s; *s = *t; *t = p;
    }
    // back to original
}
```

Comment: If you are going to golf this code, `*s ^= *t; *t ^= *s;` (restored by `*t ^= *s; *s ^= *t;`) can be shorter. But `t` must start at `s+1` this way.

Comment: Very smart!! But why "t must start at s+1" ?

Comment: If `t` and `s` refer to the same memory position, `*s ^= *t;` will make `*s` irreversibly zero. You can also skip the first value if this happens. But it may be longer if you treat R plane in a special way.

Comment: Oh, right! ....

Comment: and the language is ...

Comment: Hello @edc65! You also from Italy and 1965 born ...

Comment: @giuliolunati What? What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (E6)

I don't like the I/O format, these should be byte arrays or the like. Anyway.
Source not golfed.

```
S=(a,p)=>{
  b = a.match(/../g);    // String to array 
  l = b.length/3;        // Plane size
  s = p<'G'?2:p>'G'?0:1; // Which plane

  for (j=0, i=s; b[i]; j++, i+=3) // Shuffle
    [b[i],b[j]] = [b[j],b[i]];
  console.log(b.slice(0,l).join('')); // Output plane

  for (; i-=3, j--; ) // Unshuffle
    [b[i],b[j]] = [b[j],b[i]];

  console.log(b.join('')) // Original is back         
}
```

**Usage**

In firefox console:

```
S('00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEE','G')
```

**Output**

```
114477AADD
00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEE
```